# I want upload a file using Java and Cgi.

Tags: java, html, cgi

I was searching on the Internet and i didnt find nothing. I have to do a web aplication, and I have to upload a file. 
I have to call from html a bash that calls a .java file that upload selected file from the html. I know that CGI is outdated, but my teacher does not know... Thanks :-)

here is the part of html code that I use to select a file from my computer :

```
<h2>Upload your Revoltigrama.</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/file" method="post">
    <input id="my-file" type="file" />
    </form>
```

Comment: “… call from html a bash that calls a .java file that upload selected file from the html”—that’s impossible

Answer (score 0):

ok, you have to Open the file with JAVA and then save a copy of the document where you want  to upload the document....